# Deleting certain words from filename

Tags: bash

I have a set of files that when processed in my software, they come out with a different name (denoting that it successfully completed the process).

For example, the input file may read SAM111_tsta.fastq and then come out as SAM111_tstaAligned.SortbyCoord.bam.

I am wondering, if there is a way (via command line) to sift through a directory recursively and locate all files that have 'Aligned.SortbyCoord.bam" and have only 'Aligned.SortbyCoord' removed so that I end up with 'SAM111_tsta.bam?

Comment: Which flavour of Linux are you using?

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: @jasonwryan: he's trying to rename files, not modify their content...

Comment: Withdrawing my answer as MacOS find/xargs are aeons behind ... "find . -name \*Aligned.SortbyCoord\* | xargs -n1 sh -c 'echo $0 && echo $0 | sed -e s/Aligned.SortbyCoord//'| xargs -n2 echo mv" ... sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you have find resembling [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html). You should be able to do something like:

```
find dir -name '*_tstaAligned.SortbyCoord.bam' -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0/_tstaAligned.SortbyCoord.bam/_tsta.bam}"' "{}" \;
```

Though the bash `${var//find_all/substitute_with_this}` is used, you will only match the files ending with `_tstaAligned.SortbyCoord.bam` as that is the pattern given to `find`. You would, however, replace every occurrence of `_tstaAligned.SortbyCoord.bam` in the name, if any file has several. (Unlikely I guess.)

For testing do something like:

```
find dir -name '*tstaAligned.SortbyCoord.bam' -exec bash -c 'printf "mv \"%s\" \"%s\"\n" "$0" "${0/_tstaAligned.SortbyCoord.bam/_tsta.bam}"' "{}" \;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's the rename command,

```
find -name '*Aligned.SortbyCoord.bam' -exec rename Aligned.SortbyCoord '' + \;
```

which it turns out is in [util-linux](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/) so you'd have to install it, the package has some nice things in it.

Or you could fix up a plain list with

```
find -name '*Aligned.SortbyCoord.bam' \
| sed -E 's/(.*)Aligned.*/mv "&" "\1.bam"/e'
```

if your sed's new enough, or

```
find -name '*Aligned.SortbyCoord.bam' \
| sed -E 's/(.*)Aligned.*/mv "&" "\1.bam"/' \
| sh -x
```

if it's not, or you can make a quickie shell function to do it,

```
doit () { while read; do mv "$REPLY" "${REPLY%Aligned*}.bam"; done; }
find -name '*Aligned.SortbyCoord.bam' | doit
```

or as a oneliner

```
find -name '*Aligned.SortbyCoord.bam' | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f%A*}.bam"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the below command in the directory where you suspect the unwanted files are present :

Find . -iname "*Aligned.SortbyCoord.bam*" | xargs rm -f

I would recommend to run the find command first to validate that required files coming as output and then delete them using xargs rm -f.